# Select Index Changed event is triggering two times

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Here is a sample of my code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item first.");
    }
    else
    {
        string name = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        Binddata(name);
    }
}

public void Binddata(string name)
{
    textBox1.Text=name;            
}
```

My Windows From will look like this:

[image: Form]

When I click on Item1 for the first time the textbox is displaying Item1. But then if I click on Item2, the number of selected items is becoming "0", so it is showing the message as "Please select an item first." and if I press ok, again the event is getting triggered and Item2 is getting binded.

Please help me out in this if I am missing any thing. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you can ommit your check on Items-count. This is due to the fact, that when you click another item, the first selected item looses its focus and therefor a changeEvent is fired. The second event is fired because another item gets the focus. You may check if the name you´re putting to BindData is empty instead...

Comment: show your form_int and form_load event's code..........

Comment: @ HimBromBeere I am Checking the items count because when i clicked on item2 after selecting item1 the count is becoming "0". And I am getting the name in Binddata correct only as it is getting displayed when i pressed OK in message box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that happens, I think it fires once for unselecting the previous selected item, and second time for selecting new item.

As a workaround use `Timer` like this.

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 50 };
        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (x, y) =>
        {
            timer.Tick -= handler;
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Dispose();

            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an item first.");
            }
            else
            {
                string name = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
                Binddata(name);
            }
        };
        timer.Tick += handler;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: @satyanarayana You're welcome, you need to overcome situations for multi select also, when deselecting items also this fill fire multiple times. Take this code as a good start and build it up :)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior.  The only abnormal part is the fact that you are throwing a MessageBox when no item is selected.  The ListView can have zero items selected and you need to handle that gracefully.

If you don't like this behavior you should use the `ListBox` control which can always require 1 item selected and won't throw multiple SelectedIndexChanged events.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When the user selects an item without pressing CTRL to perform a
>   multiple selection, the control first clears the previous selection.
>   In this case, this event occurs one time for each item that was
>   previously selected and one time for the newly selected item.

You can check if any item is selected in other event handler such as button click.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior of single-select control. Refer the link for more details:

http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/listviewselectedindexchanged.html